# Dynamically access RECORD value in pl/pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, record

Why does accessing a value of the RECORD argument like this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TT_GetVal1(a RECORD)
RETURNS text AS $$
  DECLARE
  BEGIN
    RETURN a.val1::text;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT TT_GetVal1(foo.*)
FROM (SELECT 1 id, 'a' val1) foo;
```

But not like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TT_GetVal2(a RECORD)
RETURNS text AS $$
  DECLARE
    query text;
    result text;
  BEGIN
    query = 'SELECT ($1).val1::text';
    EXECUTE query INTO result USING a;
    RETURN result;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT TT_GetVal2(foo.*)
FROM (SELECT 1 id, 'a' val1) foo;
```

which returns:

```
ERROR:  could not identify column "val1" in record data type
LINE 1: SELECT ($1).val1::text
```

How can I dynamically access RECORD values?

Comment: Which version are you using? Neither function works for me with v10.7. I'm honestly surprised that #1 worked since type `RECORD` is like a C `void *`, totally amorphous and clearly resistant to any kind of type safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RECORD only lives inside the plpgsql scope.  The values are passed to the execute but not the column names.

You can - if the record is from a table - do something like this:

```
create table table1 (
  id integer,
  val1 text
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TT_GetVal2(a RECORD)
RETURNS text AS $$
  DECLARE
    query text;
    result text;
  BEGIN
    query = 'SELECT ($1::text::table1).val1';
    EXECUTE query INTO result USING a;
    RETURN result;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT TT_GetVal2(foo)
FROM (SELECT 1 id, 'a' val1) foo;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni